# How to recreate the "visual bell" effect on OSX

Tags: swift, macos

If one goes to System Preferences -> Accessibility and under the Audio section there is a checkbox for "Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs" when the system encounters a "bell" character, it will flash the screen.

Assuming this checkbox is enabled, the screen flash can be triggered by running `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to beep'` or `printf "\a"`

I have found many threads explaining how to **disable** this effect, but I am having difficulty finding any source explaining how to manually trigger this `visual effect` or implement it in your own application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import AudioToolbox
```

and play the sound

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_FlashScreen)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is *exactly* what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for the [`NSBeep()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1473622-nsbeep) function.

Comment: The tone is not the part that I'm looking for, I'm trying to look up how to trigger the visual affect that is done when the visual beep setting is enabled. If you use the test button from the accessibility -> audio section you should be able to see the effect I'm trying to explain

Comment: If that setting is enabled, then `NSBeep()` will flash the screen. Were you trying to flash the screen when that setting is disabled?